# IF statment for variables in Action Script 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Im building a sample pad type instrument for a project, i have four channels for four different instruments the interface has four buttons to select the instrument, when the button is selected the image should be green but when another instrument is selected it should go to the second frame of the movie clip which is a red button to signal them instrument is off.

Line 23 i added a conditional statment for the variable associated with the channels it doesnt spit out any errors but also doesnt change the image when i click another button anyone know where im going wrong

```
//import flash stuff

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

stop();

//event listener for the power button

poweroff.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick1);

function mouseClick1(event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop(1);
}

//select which samples to use with event listener,
//changes var selector bellow, so input listens for
//different samples

drumSelector.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, drumClick);
function drumClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
selector = drums;
if (selector == drums) 
{
drumSelector.gotoAndStop(1);
}else{
drumSelector.gotoAndStop(2);
}

}

bassSelector.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bassClick);
function bassClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
selector = bass;
}

synthSelector.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, synthClick);
function synthClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
selector = synth;
}

beatSelector.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, beatClick);
function beatClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
selector = beat;
}

//selects which movieclip samples to use for input

var selector:MovieClip = drums;


//listen for events on display keyboard
//make movieclips visible so they can play samples

key1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, key1Click);
function key1Click(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
selector.i1.visible=true;
}

key2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, key2Click);
function key2Click(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
selector.i2.visible=true;
}

key3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, key3Click);
function key3Click(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
selector.i3.visible=true;
}

key4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, key4Click);
function key4Click(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
selector.i4.visible=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new function for conditional like:

```
function updateSelector(){

  if (selector == drums) 
  {
      drumSelector.gotoAndStop(1);
  }else{
      drumSelector.gotoAndStop(2);
  }
}
```

Then in each button handler:

```
bassSelector.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bassClick);

function bassClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    selector = bass;
    updateSelector();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your conditional is only executed when you click the drumSelector button because it's inside the drumSelector click handler. You should move your conditional into a separate function and call it from the click handler of each of the four buttons which control the instruments.